How to use slick carousel rows and slidesPerRow on responsive display?
I want my carousel items on the ff conditions:

3 rows and 3 slidesPerRow on large desktop above.
2 rows and 2 slidesPerRow on less than 992px.
1 rows and 1 slidesPerRow on less than 768px.

But it seems that the rows and slidesPerRow are not working on small desktop below?. It always shows the large desktop settings?
You can check/run the codes below:


$(function() {
  $('.slick-slider-multiple').slick({
      rows: 3,
      slidesPerRow: 3,
      responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 992,
        settings: {
          rows: 2,
          slidesPerRow: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          rows: 1,
          slidesPerRow: 1,
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slick-slider-multiple">
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 8</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 9</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 10</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 11</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 12</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 13</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 14</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 15</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 16</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 17</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 18</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 19</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 20</h1>
        </div>
    </div>




It worked using the slick.jsinstead of slick.min.js. I don't know why, but I think theres a broken code on slick.min.js version 1.8.1.
I will keep this question open. Because I hope that my question will be answered using javascript, jquery on resize or any other ways to fix it using our slick.min.js.
Check the updated code below:


$(function() {
  $('.slick-slider-multiple').slick({
      rows: 3,
      slidesPerRow: 3,
      responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 992,
        settings: {
          rows: 2,
          slidesPerRow: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          rows: 1,
          slidesPerRow: 1,
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>

<div class="slick-slider-multiple">
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 8</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 9</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 10</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 11</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 12</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 13</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 14</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 15</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 16</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 17</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 18</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 19</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-single-slide">
            <h1>Slick Slide 20</h1>
        </div>
    </div>



